# Is Firebase Cloud Messaging free?

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need to implement push notification feature in my application. Exploring some options.

Google recently recommends Firebase platform, but this is not completely a free service. So I thought of using GCM again. Will google stop support for GCM in future?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

[Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) is free of charge, just like Google Cloud Messaging was. The [Firebase pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) shows exactly what Firebase features are paid.

Comment: Is there a cap or limit for free Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Comment: @conandor No, there is not.

Comment: In order to use Firebase push services - should I have Google Cloud Platform account?

Answer (score 23):

Yes, it's free. You can use Analytics for advanced messaging - out of the box.

> **Which products are paid? Which are free**?
>
> Firebase's paid infrastructure products are the Realtime Database,
>   Firebase Storage, Hosting, and Test Lab. We offer a free tier for all
>   of these products except Test Lab.
>
> Firebase also has many free products: Analytics, Notifications, Crash
>   Reporting, Authentication, Remote Config, Dynamic Links, Firebase
>   Invites, and App Indexing. You can use an unlimited amount of these in
>   all plans, including our free Spark Plan.

Comment: where did you get this resource?

Answer (score 9):

As of April 10, 2018, Google has deprecated GCM. The GCM server and client APIs are deprecated and will be removed as soon as April 11, 2019. Migrate GCM apps to Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM), which inherits the reliable and scalable GCM infrastructure.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted; that's correct information. The original question was: "Will google stop support for GCM in future?" And, the answer is yes: GCM API's have been removed already. See https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm

Answer (score 5):

https://firebase.google.com/pricing/

This link should help you understand better. If you are implementing push notifications my suggestion would be that maintain your own database for the generated device tokens instead of using topic messaging.

Two reasons why I avoided topic subscription is :

1. There is a limit to the number of topics you can subscribe in free plan
2. Topics are not subscribed immediately

Although the number of active users allowed in parallel connection has a limit but its too much to exceed that easily.

P.S. I use the spark plan by the way

Comment: There is not a limit: https://developers.googleblog.com/2015/12/google-cloud-messaging-weve-come-long.html

Comment: More than 6 months have passed on your answer, was wondering how is the spark plan holding up with you so far :)? care to share the number of users you have now? @dinesh-shekhawat

Comment: The spark plan is working fine for me. As for now there are no users but when I was using FirebaseStorage for another project no problem  was faced.

Comment: @Sti The spark plan will be free till you hit the limits. After that they start charging. And also if you are making any external API calls, you need to get the paid service. Else you'll get errors

Comment: @Lokesh I didn't say the spark plan was free. My comment was a response to the answer stating that "There is a limit to the number of topics". The link I provided states that "we’re allowing unlimited free topics for your app". I.E "there is no limit".
Also, this is about a year ago, so who knows what Google has been doing. Maybe it's super expensive now, like they did with GoogleMaps, which we can't afford to use anymore.

Answer (score 5):

There is no such thing "unlimited" for free.
If you will send billions of billions messages a day, you will likely hit the maximum throughput limits and get blocked, or perhaps some sales man will contact you.

Answer (score 1):

It’s free but limited with rates - see https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

No clue how Telegrams handles to work with this at their 700M active users paste.
My guess they opened hundreds of cloudflare projects and invoke the api in a round robin with some custom proxies and load balancers.

Answer (score -4):

Not completely free. This is the pricing strategy.

https://firebase.google.com/pricing